# How to solve SHIFT/REDUCE conflict - in parser generator

Tags: parsing, shift-reduce-conflict, cup

I need help to solve this one and explanation how to deal with this SHIFT/REDUCE CONFLICTS in future.

I have some conflicts between few states in my cup file.

Grammer look like this:

I have conflicts between "(" [ActPars] ")" states.

```
1. Statement = Designator ("=" Expr | "++" | "‐‐" | "(" [ActPars] ")" ) ";"

2. Factor = number | charConst | Designator [ "(" [ActPars] ")" ].
```

---

I don't want to paste whole 700 lines of cup file. 
I will give you the relevant states and error output.

This is code for the line 1.)

```
Matched ::= Designator LPAREN ActParamsList RPAREN SEMI_COMMA

ActParamsList ::=  ActPars
               |
               /* EPS */
               ;

ActPars ::= Expr
        |
        Expr ActPComma
        ;

ActPComma ::= COMMA ActPars;
```

This is for the line 2.)

```
Factor ::= Designator ActParamsOptional ;


ActParamsOptional ::= LPAREN ActParamsList2 RPAREN
              |
              /* EPS */
              ;

ActParamsList2 ::= ActPars
               |
               /* EPS */
               ;

Expr ::= SUBSTRACT Term RepOptionalExpression
         |
         Term RepOptionalExpression
         ;
```

**The ERROR output looks like this:**

```
Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #182
between ActParamsOptional ::= LPAREN ActParamsList RPAREN (*) 
and     Matched ::= Designator LPAREN ActParamsList RPAREN (*) SEMI_COMMA 
under symbol SEMI_COMMA
Resolved in favor of shifting.
```

Error : *** More conflicts encountered than expected -- parser generation aborted

Comment: I think `ActParamsList2` has unbalanced parentheses. An example for an expanded `ActParamsOptional` would look like this: `(Expr))`.

Comment: Yes you are right - I have changed that - that was mistake. I have changed that and updated error output as new shift reduce appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your parser won't know if it should shift to the token:

```
SEMI_COMMA
```

or reduce to the token

```
ActParamsOptional
```

since the tokens defined in both `ActParamsOptional` and `Matched` are

```
LPAREN ActPars RPAREN
```

Comment: And the solution is to give more of a lookahead, or switch up your grammar into something non-ambiguous. For example, replace the parens with square brackets for one of the tokens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - is there some other way - I have to keep this syntax - I have to keep parenthases "(" [ActPars] ")"  - you can see how this needs to look like at the beginning of my post ( lines named 1. And 2.) And I can't use precedence keyword because they told us not to use it :-(

Comment: @MilanBojovic I've tried to go through it and see the grammar but I'm still a bit confused as to what these items represent. Could you give a few lines of example showing what the language looks like?

Comment: Ok I will give you the examples for the first and second line:
1.)
    int i = 0; a = 10; b = 5;
    i = add(a,b);
Or:
    int i = 0;
    i = functionWithoutActualParameters();

Comment: BTW Language is Micro Java.
And well if you follow first line 1.) Statement = Designator = Expr (Expression) and Expression can eventually guide us to the second one 2.) Example: Expr = Factor = number | charConst | Designator [ "(" [ActPars] ")" ]. Maybe that leads to the problem - but how can I change this lines which are conflicted so Parser can make difference between them ? Sorry if I am little confused

Comment: @MilanBojovic I'm not sure if this is the same language (MiniJava), but take a look at how they represent [their grammar](http://www.cambridge.org/resources/052182060X/MCIIJ2e/grammar.htm).